# How to display the format of time as hh:mm

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

I have tried to display the time in asp.net using "hh : mm : ss tt" this format in html code as showing below:

```
                        <tr>
                            <td class="col-md-9">Arrival Time: </td>
                            <td class="col-md-3">
                                <i area-hidden="true">
                                </i>@Model.Time.Value.ToString("hh : mm : ss tt"))
                            </td>
                        </tr>
```

I am getting the user input using view html as below:

```
   <div class="form-group row">
    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Arrival Time</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input class="form-control" style="width:300px" asp-for="Time" 
     min="9:00" max="12:00" type="time">
```

But it runs into an error that says:

```
 FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
 System.Globalization.TimeSpanFormat.FormatCustomized(TimeSpan value, ReadOnlySpan<char> format, 
 DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, StringBuilder result)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[C# DateTime Format](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/date-and-time-format-in-c-sharp-programming1)

I think you should replace time type to `datetime` and use the follow format:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss tt")
```

Comment: Thank you for your help